Geometry Node connections to Group Input Node not working anymore
For some reason I cannot connect newly created input to anything, even to a reroute.
It does this for all new inputs but the old ones still working fine.
I have this error message in the log: Property type does not match input socket "Name of the input"
The input were created using the + button in the group node interface but the same thing happen when I just drag a connection to the empty slot at the bottom of the Group Input node. The connection just doesn't happen.

In this image, "Use Vertex Group?" and "Supports Vertex Group" are the new inputs and it's impossible to connect them to anything. The same error message appear.

They don't appear in the Modifier Panel
Do you know how I could solve this issue? Did I reached the maximum of input I can use?
I'm using Blender 4.2
Thank you :)
Edit:
Blender file : 

I copy pasted the geometry node in a new scene, I still couldn't connect the New input to anything. I removed all the other input one by one until I found one that somehow fix the issue after I delete it. I'm not sure what is wrong about this one specifically.
I'm wondering if it's maybe because the original geometry node group was created a while ago in Blender 3.5. I can see some input being NodesModifier.Socket_## and some NodesModifier.Input_##

Never had this problem before. It's probably best to upload your file to check if there is something wrong with the settings.

Test on a fresh copy of Blender without any addons. If problem persists, remove everything else and upload .blend: How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice

Thank you for the suggestion. I've added the node group to an clean empty scene and removed all the inputs of the node group until I found one that, after I remove it, allow the new input to be connected.
Since I removed all the input nodes ( I had a lot of them) all newly created input work again.
I updated the post with the file so you can try yourself.

Opened the file in Blender 4.2.0 (2024-07-16; 06:20; a51f293548ad) and I can see an error in modifier stack:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Property type does not match input socket "(New input created before removing all the other inputs)"

Interestingly, you're wrong that the string input causes an issue, because when you drag it above the float input, it now works, and the float input stops working. This means the issue is related to the order or number of inputs rather than one particular input.
I think you're right here:

I'm wondering if it's maybe because the original geometry node group was created a while ago in Blender 3.5. I can see some input being NodesModifier.Socket_## and some NodesModifier.Input_##

In particular, two inputs share the same identifier and that's probably what causes the problem: once Blender encounters a duplicate it refuses to further parse the data:
>>> group = D.node_groups['Geometry Node input issue']
>>> group.interface.items_tree[2].identifier
'Socket_22'

>>> group.interface.items_tree[3].identifier
'Socket_22'

As for the fix, you figured it, removing the problematic sockets. I'd remove and restore all sockets, so that all identifiers start with Socket_.

Thank you so much for your investigation and detailed answer! I'll try that :) I have a looot of input in my case, so I was wondering if maybe there was a limit but the identifier clash makes sense. Perhaps I can try to make a script to go through each input and change them if needed. Hopefully it will work.
